# How to install Magento Shared Packages?

Tags: magento2, composer, marketplace, composer.json

I have a magento extension

- Vendorname/module1-core

I have now uploaded a shared packaged which is approved

- vendorname/module1-extension

moodule1 extension has a require section with

```
"vendorname/module1-core": ">=1.4.1"
```

When I do composer require vendorname/module1-core:1.4.1, I only see module1 I don't see a shared package. I don't know how to get it. Both are approved and live on marketplace.

**Edit 1:** I tried the way user [sushant kumar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/40069/sushant-kumar) said in first comment it does not work. In my case which I mentioned, `module1-core` is the one which is uploaded and certified as Magento Extension does not have any dependency on `module1-extension`. `module1-extension` is a shared packaged. and just to give it a try, I did the following `composer require vendor/module1-core:1.4.4 --with-dependencies`, it installs only the core module and not the extension module that is uploaded as a shared package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a package with its dependent extensions/plugin/library, you should probably pass the argument **--with-dependencies or --with-all-dependencies**.

For example **`composer require vendor/package --with-dependencies`**

**`composer require vendor/package --with-all-dependencies`**

Comment: In my case which I mentioned, ```module1-core``` is the one which is uploaded and certified as Magento Extension does not have any dependency on ```module1-extension```. ```module1-extension``` is a shared packaged.